Intuition behind the definition of Tractor Connection & Tractor Bundle
This is a supplementary question of this question. Jeffrey Case wrote an excellent answer. I would like to know if there is any way someone could come up "naturally" with the definition of the Tractor connection.
Let $(M^n, [g])$ be a conformal manifold. Recall that the standard tractor connection on the tractor bundle $\mathcal{T}^A$ with respect to given a choice of metric $g$ in the conformal class $[g]$, is given by the formula:
$$ \nabla_j \begin{pmatrix} \sigma \\ v^i \\ \rho \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \nabla_j\sigma - v_j \\ \nabla_j v^i + \sigma P_j^i + \delta_j^i\rho \\ \nabla_j\rho - P_{ji}v^i \end{pmatrix} . $$
Here $P_{ij}=\frac{1}{n-2}\left( R_{ij} - \frac{R}{2(n-1)}g\right)$ is the Schouten tensor and $n=\dim M$ (copied from Jeffrey's answer). It can be shown via explicit calculation that this connection is conformally independent. That's good because we are eventually looking for conformally invariant objects of the conformal manifold $(M^n, [g]).$ This definition eventually leads to the notion of (conformal) Tractor curvature and other conformally invariant objects. I have no doubts about the usefulness of this connection, but my question is: How could someone come up with such a definition?
Note that I know one situation where someone might tend to derive such a connection. Suppose we are looking for Einstein metrics in the conformal class of a fixed given metric $g.$ Finding such a metric $\hat{g} = \sigma^{-2} g$ is equivalent to finding a solution $\sigma$ to the system of PDEs $(Ric(\hat{g}))_{\circ}=0. $ Note that the $\circ$ represents the trace-free part of the tensor. Eventually, this leads to the following linear PDE:
$(\nabla_i \nabla_j \sigma + P_{ij}\sigma)_{\circ} =0,$ and then the classic prolongation techniques lead to a system of linear PDEs:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \nabla_j\sigma - v_j \\ \nabla_j v^i + \sigma P_j^i + \delta_j^i\rho \\ \nabla_j\rho - P_{ji}v^i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ This seems a good source of motivation for such a definition, but I am not very happy with this. Maybe there is a "better" way to come up with such a definition. To me, this definition looks like adding some "extra terms" with the usual definition of connection, but I cannot immediately see what should be some extra terms to make the definition invariant on $\mathcal{T}^A.$
Moreover, Jeffrey Case defined the tractor bundle by identifying conformal densities as the following:
Given another metric $\hat g \mathrel{:=} e^{2\Upsilon}g\in [g]$, we identify $(\sigma,v^i,\rho)\in\mathcal{T}_g^A$ with $(\hat\sigma,\hat v^i,\hat\rho)\in\mathcal{T}_{\hat g}^A$ if
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \hat\sigma \\ \hat v^i \\ \hat\rho \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma \\ v^i + \sigma\Upsilon^i \\ \rho - \Upsilon_j v^j - \frac{1}{2}\Upsilon^2\sigma \end{pmatrix} . $$ We can show that this identification gives an equivalent relation, and more importantly, this identification leads to the conformal invariance of the connection defined before. That means everything was defined perfectly! Again my question is: How could we derive such identifications? More precisely, is there any way one could come up with the notion of Tractor bundles without using machinery such as the Associated bundle of some principle bundle? The definition here is such one, but to me, it lacks the motivation for defining such a bundle. Could anyone derive this identification from somewhere to construct $\mathcal{T}^A$? I would be thankful if you could spend some time defining the Tractor bundle with some geometric/algebraic motivation and, most importantly, pointing out how this particular identification came up "naturally." Thank you very much.
